# Symfony2 - add new Request-type code

Tags: symfony

I want to execute a bundle on every request (some additional Request actions).

I can see how to route a controller for a request to a web URL, but not sure the best way to go about this.

I'm thinking I could change the app_dev.php/app.php files but this doesn't seem very good. I don't think I am supposed to 'extend' the current Request class either.

I've also looked at Events, and think this might be a possible idea.

Because it will be executed on every request, I don't want to break any of the good stuff Symfony2 is doing (as rubbish code could really slow down a site if it is executed so often).

What is the best standards way to perform additional actions (in my bundle) on every request?

I don't really need code, just a simple 'yes, change the app.php file' or point in the right direction.

I've read the manual from start to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) are the way to go and you might find information about the event you need [in this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html).

Event listeners kind of works like [Services](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/service_container.html) so that might be worth checking out.